# How to call data-style within a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, dataset

I would like to show or hide the following div via jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image" data-style="bw"><img src="img/bw1.jpg"></div>
<div class="image" data-style="fauna"><img src="img/fauna1.jpg"></div>
<div class="image" data-style="bw"><img src="img/bw2.jpg"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let images=document.querySelectorAll ("image"); 
let genre = "bw";

images.dataset.style.genre.show();
```

Somehow I get an error `images.dataset` is `undefined` what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like following.

```
$('[data-style="bw"]').show();
```